# Extract values between nth and (n+1)th occurrence of a character

Tags: arrays, python-3.5

I have multiple lines in a csv file, and each `line look like this

```
0.10089;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0;-0.9;-0.35;999999;0;0;0;80;81.226;158.25;0;
```

I have to replace the values `-0.9`, `-0.35` and `999999` by `2*` those values, `-0.9` becomes `-1.8`...

I have declared an array, `sc_pos_array` that stores the index of all the semicolons that appear in every `line`

`sc_pos_array = [i for i,x in enumerate(line) if x == ';']`

I know that the value `0.9` occurs after the `10th` semicolon, and I know the index of the `10th` semicolon from `sc_pos_array[9]`. To access `0.9`, I then write

`line[sc_pos_array[9]+1]:line[sc_pos_array[10]]`

but this doesn't seem to work. I am doing all this inside the following `for` loop

`with fileinput.input(inplace=True) as f:
    for line in f:
        ...`

Comment: It's not clear what "doesn't seem to work" means, but I highly recommend to change your approach. You'll find it much easier to use existing tools, such as the `csv` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the value 0.9:

```
line[sc_pos_array[9]+1 : sc_pos_array[10]]
```

The following code replaces the value -0.9 and substitues its 2x value back in the string:

```
line = line[0:sc_pos_array[9] + 1] + str(2 * float(line[sc_pos_array[9]+1 : sc_pos_array[10]])) + line[sc_pos_array[10]:]
print line
```

Hence the output is:

```
'0.10089;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;0-1.8;-0.35;999999;0;0;0;80;81.226;158.25;0;'
```

Comment: Thank you! It works for the most part, but instead of -1.8, it displays 0-1.8

Comment: @AnandDwivedi you are correct. I updated the solution. To get the 9th ';' you need to go to i +1th index.

Comment: Right now I run the script using `python3 script.py file.csv`. I was trying to use 'argparse' to ask the user for the number which they want to multiply (instead of explicitly using 2)
`ap.add_argument("-m", "--multiplier", required = True, help = "number to multiply with x,y,z values")

args = vars(ap.parse_args())` and then using `args["multiplier"]` in place of `2`, but this doesn't seem to work